# Proceeds JOIN only if condition met on the Owner table

Tags: query-performance, sqlite, performance-tuning, android, sqlite3

I have many hasOne relationships like this:

- components

  - component_headings
  - component_images

Here one Component can only have one hasOne to any of [headings, images].

Logically when a `Component.type = heading` then it can only have one Heading relation no other relation.

Currently, I'm writing SQL queries like this:

```sql
SELECT Component.id, Component.type, Component.`order` FROM Component

LEFT JOIN ComponentHeading ON Component.type = 'heading' AND ComponentHeading.component_id = ContentComponent.id

LEFT JOIN ComponentImage ON Component.type = 'image' AND ComponentImage.component_id = ContentComponent.id
```

I feel the Query might not be optimized to the best.

Thanks.

Comment: This query would always return 0 rows because it's logically inequivalent. This query is saying that for every row the field `Component.type` has to equal the values both `heading` and `image` on the same row at the same time, which is impossible (because you're using an implicit `INNER JOIN` on both clauses). Think you might have a logic issue not a performance one.

Comment: Okay, I fixed my mistake, I was actually meaning LEFT JOIN. Can you please take a look now? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't optimized? Does it cause performance issues? Is that a measurable thing? Have you considered adding covering indexes?

Comment: I feel there might be some better ways to write these types of things. That's just it. Haven't faced any performance issues. asked experts just to make sure. Thanks.